# Would cuDNN v6.0 work with TensorFlow currently?

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

Do we specifically need cuDNN v5.1 (as suggested) for TensorFlow, or would the latest version (v6.0) work as well? Is there backward compatibility in cuDNN versions?

Comment: The latest version (TensorFlow 1.0.1) did not work with cuDNN v6 for me.(as of April 1).

Comment: Ah, thank you. Then cuDNN versions are likely not backward compatible and with every new version, we need to wait for any infrastructure to be upgraded/tweaked for the new version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, cuDNN 6.0 is not supported in the latest 1.2 version. But there is a hope: the official [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.2.0) tell the following:

> TensorFlow 1.2 may be the last time we build with cuDNN 5.1. Starting
>   with TensorFlow 1.3, we will try to build all our prebuilt binaries
>   with cuDNN 6.0. While we will try to keep our source code compatible
>   with cuDNN 5.1, it will be best effort.

So hopefully the next 1.3 version will use cuDNN 6.0. Especially now, when [7.0 is right around the corner](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn).

Answer (score 2):

Today ( 21 August 2017 ) I installed the latest Tensorflow release v1.3 and I can confirm that it **REQUIRES** cuDNN v6.0 and **WILL NOT WORK with v5.1** . It will ask in fact for the library libcudnn.so.6 and not the libcudnn.so.5

P.s. If you want it to work with cuDNN 5.1. you can install a previous version e.g. v1.2 which is at this link:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#virtualenv_installation

Answer (score 1):

This would be an updated answer of [Salvador Dali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994772/5330223)'s response.

I have upgraded the `tensorflow` version to `1.2.1` and then `cudnn 6.0` seems to work with no problem. I used `pip`

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Installation details are [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/).